# Using arrays to model physical line with text image output

Tags: c++, arrays

I am currently working on a C++ Programming project, however I cannot seem to get arrays done correctly. I am following this guide, on page 2 of 8.

http://www.joehummel.net/uploads/cs109-hw7-pe1.pdf

I wrote a For loop to print out all of the information in the matrix, but for an unknown reason, my output is just 2 lines of code which is just "t" and "0", instead of the whole grid.

```
void fill(int M[][N], int ROWS, int COLS, int row, int col)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (i<ROWS;i++;)
    {
        for (j<COLS;j++;)
        {
            cout <<"0"<< M[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "T" << M[row][col];   
}
```

Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated! Thank You!

Comment: You increment looks to be in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

`for (i<ROWS;i++;)`

you want

`for (i;i<ROWS;i++)`

or

`for (;i<ROWS;i++)`

Reasoning: The sections of a for loop go initialization (run once before everything), check (before each loop, if it evaluates to false break), update (run once after each loop ends)

Comment: In class, I am used to doing for `(int i = 0; i<ROWS;i++)` but I'm writing in Devc++ and it's giving me errors for even putting "i" in there as well as requiring me to put a semicolon after increasing i.  Is it the program or is it my code?

Comment: @julesverne Some flavours of C make it illegal to initialize in the first part of the for loop - but you still need your semicolons in the right place, one before the check and one before the update - so that it knows what is what.

Comment: so I rechecked the prompt and reread the bottom of page 4 and realized I'm trying to print the matrix where I'm supposed to just fill it with 0 and print all the 0's in the print function, but I'm still just getting an output of T0

Answer (score 0):

```
void fill(int M[][N], int ROWS, int COLS, int row, int col)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < COLS ; j++)
        {
            cout << "0" << M[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "T" << M[row][col];   
}
```